# How to remove class if exist?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can we handle multiple toggleclass in 1 div it gets so annoying when I click maximize button or close button the minimize function will fire too. How can we handle that?

How can we handle multiple toggleclass in 1 div it gets so annoying when I click maximize button or close button the minimize function will fire too. How can we handle that?

```js
    jQuery(($) => {

    const $chatbox = $(".chatbox");
    const $open = $(".open-chatbox");
    const $minimize = $(".minimize-chatbox");
    const $maximize = $(".maximize-chatbox");
    const $close = $(".close-chatbox");
    const $chatboxTextarea = $("textarea");
  
    $open.on("click", function() {
      const $showChatbox = $chatbox.removeClass("hide-chatbox");
      console.log($showChatbox);
    });

    $minimize.on("click", function() {
        const $minimizeChatbox = $chatbox.toggleClass("minimize");
        console.log($minimizeChatbox);
    });

    let maximized = false;
    $maximize.on("click", function() {
        const $maximizeChatbox = $chatbox.toggleClass("maximize");
        maximized = !maximized;
        $chatboxTextarea.attr("rows", maximized ? 6 : null);
        console.log($maximizeChatbox);
    });

    $close.on("click", function() {
      const $hideChatbox = $chatbox.addClass("hide-chatbox");
      console.log($hideChatbox);
    });

  });
```

```css
.body {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

.chatbox {
    position: fixed;
    height: 397px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
    z-index: 10000;
    width: 325px;
    bottom: -30px;
    right: 30px;
}

.chatbox .card-header {
    color: #303030;
    border-bottom: solid 1px #8b8b8b4d;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 10px 10px 5px 10px;
}

.chatbox .card-header span.icons {
    float: right;
    color: #BEC2C9;
}

.chatbox .card-header .icons i.material-icons {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.chatbox .card-body {
    padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
}

.chatbox .card-footer {
    border-top: solid 1px #8b8b8b4d !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.form-group.type-area {
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.type-area textarea {
    width: 300px;
    border: none !important;
    padding: 0 0 0 10px;
    margin: 0;
}

.type-area .form-control:hover {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.type-area button.btn.btn-link {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.chatbox.hide-chatbox {
    display: none;
}

.chatbox.maximize {
    width: 800px;
    height: 527px;
}

.chatbox.minimize {
    height: 40px;
}

.chatbox.maximize textarea {
    width: 775px;
}

.chatbox.maximize .send {
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.minimize .maximize-chatbox {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons"
      rel="stylesheet">
<body>
<button type="button" rel="tooltip" title="Message" class="btn btn-primary btn-link btn-sm open-chatbox">
                                <i class="material-icons">chat_bubble</i>
                              </button>
  <div class="card chatbox hide-chatbox">
      <div class="card-header minimize-chatbox">
          Featured
          <span class="icons">
          <i class="material-icons maximize-chatbox">web_asset</i>
          <i class="material-icons close-chatbox">close</i>
          </span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body">
          This is some text within a card body.
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
          <form>
          <div class="form-group type-area">
              <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Type a message..."></textarea>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-link"><i class="material-icons send">send</i></button>
          </div>
          </form>
      </div>
  </div>
  
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: just chain it `$maximize.on("click", function() { $chatbox.addClass("maximize").removeClass("minimize"); });`

Comment: still didn't work

Comment: People could help better if you provide html code they can use to test your issue , not an image. [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). It's not obvious from what is shown and from your description what the specific problem is. See also [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[From jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-className) You can toggle one or more classes by passing them in *separated by spaces* so you can just call `.toggleClass("minimize maximize")` and they'll flip automatically. Of course your initial state should be one of those already applied.

> .toggleClass(className): One or more classes (separated by spaces) to be toggled for each element in the matched set.

There's also an [overload](https://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/#toggleClass-classNames) that accepts an array of classes

In case one of the buttons triggers other click events, perhaps it Bubbles see [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) or [preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) for more info, the difference is that `stopPropagation` will still allow for the default event action to be executed

In your case you can use

```js
$open.on("click", function(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
  $chatbox.removeClass("hide-chatbox");
});
```

Comment: if only i have 1 button. but i have 3 buttons

Comment: @frustrated-dev so your issue is that when you click the maximize button the minimize  event fires? perhaps it bubbles, try to preventDefault something like `$open.on("click", function(e) { e.preventDefault(); $chatbox.removeClass("hide-chatbox"); });`

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at snippet below:

**UPDATE 1:**

Also you do not need to know a class is exists *in this situation*, just remove the class, if it is exists, it'll be remove if it's not, nothing happening.

**UPDATE 2:**

According to your codes, you specify a minimize button but there is no problem to remove that.

If you have problem with `toggleClass()` you don't need to use it, just think about a workaround like using `hasClass()` instead. With this approach you can change text or icon of resize too.

```js
(function ($) {
  'use strict';

  $(function () {
    const $chatbox = $(".chatbox");
    const $open = $(".open-chatbox");
    const $maximize = $(".maximize-toggle-chatbox");
    const $close = $(".close-chatbox");
    
    function logClass(element) {
      console.log(element.attr('class'));
    }
  
    // chatbox open button click event
    $open.on("click", function() {
      // if there is no selector for chatbox
      if(!$(this).attr('data-for')) return;
      
      const current_chatbox = $($(this).attr('data-for'));
      
      // if there is no selector present with specific selector
      if(!current_chatbox.length) return;
      
      current_chatbox.removeClass("hide-chatbox");
      
      // log classes of chatbox
      logClass(current_chatbox);
    });

    // chatbox maximize button click event
    $maximize.on("click", function() {
      const current_chatbox = $(this).closest('.chatbox');
      if(current_chatbox.hasClass('maximize')) {
        current_chatbox.removeClass("maximize").addClass('minimize');
        $(this).text('maximize chat');
      } else {
        current_chatbox.removeClass("minimize").addClass('maximize');
        $(this).text('minimize chat');
      }
      
      // log classes of chatbox
      logClass(current_chatbox);
    });

    // chatbox close button click event
    $close.on("click", function() {
      const current_chatbox = $(this).closest('.chatbox');
      current_chatbox.addClass("hide-chatbox");
      
      // log classes of chatbox
      logClass(current_chatbox);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.chatbox {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 70%;
  height: 70%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.maximize {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.hide-chatbox {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button class="open-chatbox" type="button" data-for="#theChatbox">
  open chat
</button>

<div class="chatbox hide-chatbox" id="theChatbox">
  <button class="close-chatbox" type="button">
    close chat
  </button>
  
  <button class="maximize-toggle-chatbox" type="button">
    maximize chat
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: my minimize and maximize is not a vise-versa, maximize will make the chat box bigger and back to small when click back the maximize like toggle class. But it gives my annoying result when i add two or more toogle class in single div

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery `hasClass`

```
    $maximize.on("click", function() {
      
      if($(this).closest('.chatbox').hasClass('maximize')) {
        // chatbox hasClass  maxiremove it and add min
        $(this).closest('.chatbox').removeClass("maximize").addClass('minimize');
        $(this).text('maximize chat');
      } else {
        current_chatbox.removeClass("minimize").addClass('maximize');
        $(this).text('minimize chat');
      }
      
      // log classes of chatbox
      logClass(current_chatbox);
    });
```